# Page not getting refresh after form submission?

Tags: codeigniter

```
                <form id="contact-form" action="<?=site_url()?>/main/add_contact" onsubmit="return Validate()" method="POST">

                    <div class="inline-inputs">


                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <label>Name*</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> 
                            <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('username')) {?><b style="color: red"><?=$this->session->flashdata('username')?></b><?php }?>   
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <label>Phone*</label>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">     
                            <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('phone')) {?><b style="color: red"><?=$this->session->flashdata('phone')?></b><?php }?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <label>Email Address*</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">    
                            <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('email')) {?><b style="color: red"><?=$this->session->flashdata('email')?></b><?php }?>                         
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <label>Subject*</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">     
                            <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('subject')) {?><b style="color: red"><?=$this->session->flashdata('subject')?></b><?php }?> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <label>Message*</label>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="10" name="query" id="query"style = 'resize:none;'></textarea>
                            <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('query')) {?><b style="color: red"><?=$this->session->flashdata('query')?></b><?php }?>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

                </form>
```

After this form submission the action goes to the method in the controller,there i have set with validation and kept

redirect(site_url().'/main/contact','refresh');

Even though the method exists in the controller why i dont no the page is not getting refresh after the form submission..

After the form submission the page should show the flash data,it is not getting refreshed,when i manually refresh the page after the submission then i can see the flashdata..

Comment: what happen in your validate function ?

Comment: it checks wether the given details like phone are in right format or not..